# Extra \else and extra \fi error

Tags: conditionals, ifthenelse, center

I am writing a document that presents different information depending on a defined command. The code in a simple version is like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

%\usepackages ...

\title{My title}

\author{Author Name}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
  Lorem Ipsum...
\end{abstract}

% keywords can be removed
\keywords{Keyword1 -- Keyword2 -- Keyword3}

%----------------------------------------------------------
\def\coupleDocument   %States it for 2d type document.
%----------------------------------------------------------

\ifx\coupleDocument\undefined
 \begin{center}
 \small{Couple document}
 \end{center}
\else
 \begin{center}
 \small{Single document}
 \end{center}
\fi

...

\end{document}
```

This generates four errors:

1. `LaTeX Error: \begin{document} ended by \end{center}.`
2. `Extra \endgroup.`
3. `Extra \else.`
4. `Extra \fi.`

I would appreciate any help to fix this and to understand the cause of the errors.

Note: if I delete the `\ifx` block the errors vanish.

Comment: this gives the error `! Undefined control sequence.
l.17 \keywords`  also unrelated use  `\small Single document` not `\small{Single document}`  size commands do not take an argument

Comment: the main error is `\def\coupleDocument`  which should be `\def\coupleDocument{???}` depending what you intende to define this to be. as it is  the definition absorbs all tokens up to `{center}`

Comment: Yes, I didn't realize that `\small` syntax was wrong. Thanks for the observation.

Comment: test `\small{this}  this is small as well.`  the braces have no effect on the size change

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently you have

```
\def\coupleDocument   %States it for 2d type document.
%----------------------------------------------------------

\ifx\coupleDocument\undefined
 \begin{center}
```

which defines `\coupleDocument` as a commmand that must be followed by

`\par\ifx\coupleDocument\undefined\begin`
and expands to `center`

so then `\small{Couple document}` (which should be `\small Couple document` typesets text  then  `\end{center}` is seen when the current enviornment is `document`

use

`\def\coupleDocument{}`

to define the command (to empty) so that the `\ifx` test later is true.

Comment: Thanks. It actually worked but using `\empty` instead of `\undefined`. I guess that `\def\coupleDocument{}` defines a empty command, so `\undefined` is not true.

Comment: @SDEscobedo oh I thought you wanted the first branch if it was not defined at all and the second branch if it was deined to anything, in which case it wouldn't matter what you defined it to be, but whatever.

Comment: yes it was the original idea. I thought you was saying that using `\def\coupleDocument{}` was going to render the condition `\if\coupleDocument\undefined` true. It actually become false. But that's ok, It can be done both ways.

Comment: @SDEscobedo rather than have the`ifx` and an arbitrary definition it would be easier to read if you used `\ifcoupleDocument` then `\coupleDocumenttrue` (or false) and `\ifcoupleDocument aaa \else bbb\fi`